# Recursive Function: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

i call myFunc1 with counter val 2. myFunc1 calls myFunc2 and increases each time counter.

It should stop when counter val is 4.

Why does this not work?

I get error "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

```
myFunc1 = (counter) => {
    if(counter < 5) {
      myFunc2(counter);
  }
}

  myFunc2 = (counter) => {
    myFunc1(counter++);
}

myFunc1(2);
```

Comment: Did you print the values inside the function all to find out what's going on?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, i am totally beginner and i know my missing knowlegge will make hier anyone angry ;(

Comment: I'm not angry. I only taught you how to debug. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`counter++` returns the value of `counter` and *then* increments the variable. You should use `counter + 1` or `++counter` which increments, *then* returns the value.

see [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment#description)

```js
myFunc1 = (counter) => {
    if(counter < 5) {
      myFunc2(counter);
    }
}

myFunc2 = (counter) => {
    myFunc1(counter + 1);
}

myFunc1(2);
```